# Is possible to set a default value and then change the value in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, default-value

```
class Person {
   private String name;
   private String sex="male";
   public Person(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   public String getSex(){return this.sex;}
}
```

In the above class, if I want to set the default value for sex. is it OK?
then, if I want to create new Person, is the following code good?

```
Person p = new Person("mike");
String sex = p.getSex();
```

Comment: Try it out and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain constructors in Java to give certain values defaults.

For example, here's a constructor that takes a name and one that takes a name and a sex.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String sex;

    public Person(String name, String sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this(name, "male");
    }

    // getters/setters here
}
```

If your object has a lot of properties that may be optional, you should consider the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead of standard constructors.

Comment: Note that `this(whatever)` is a special keyword that says "call this other constructor with these arguments".  As far as I know, it is only valid in constructors.

Answer (score 0):

It always to good to make your class thread safe by defining the fields as final and assign the values only through constructor.

```
class Person {
   private final String name;
   private final String sex;
   public Person(String name, String sex) {
       this.name = name;
       this.sex = sex;
   }
   public String getName() { return this.name; }
   public String getSex(){return this.sex;}
}
```